# Is angular new router part of 1.5 release

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router

Is angular new router part of 1.5 release? I can't find a clear answer but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Does not look like it. It is not in the  [beta package](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2). This [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12926) might get you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [this discussion I had with Brandon Roberts](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3774) (towards the bottom), who seems to be in the know.

As at that discussion (12 Dec 2015) "It was/is planned to be released along with 1.5.0."  That's the latest I've heard.

Comment: Yep, broberts shows it working with 1.5.0.rc0:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bzmgUygZ5nPLDaU7ucHB?p=preview